# Java 8 Sorting List<Object>

Tags: java

Asking for the first time here
.So I have a `List'<'Object'>' list = new ArrayList'<'Object'>'().`

I cannot change that because of project requirement.Now I am adding `Foo` class objects to this list.
My code goes like this.

```
 List<Object> ls = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Foo foo: fooList) {
    //  Foo setters
}
ls.add( foo);


// Foo class goes like
public class Foo{
    private String name;
    private String status;
```

Now I want to sort ls (List of Object) based on foo status.
Sorry if format is not correct , Also I cant change a lot in code.Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of adding line breaks on each line, just indent all the code by 4 spaces to format it.

Comment: Show sample input and expected output, along with what you've tried.

Comment: What's the problem with sorting? You have a list of `Object` so any comparator needs to check whether the objects it gets are `Foo` instances or something else. If they both are, compare based on the property you need, if they aren't use some kind of fallback (e.g. define `Foo` to be greater/smaller than `Object`).

Comment: You probably want the list to be a `List<Foo>`, not `List<Object>`, and you probably want the `ls.add(foo)` statement *inside* the `for` loop. Then to sort, you either need to make `Foo` implement `Comparable`, or you need a `Comparator`, and there are lots of articles on the web showing both, so **do some research**, i.e. search the web. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Andreas I already mentioned I cannot change List<Object> to List<Foo> , it was my restriction , sorting List<Foo> was vanilla.
Labosis answer was my requirement.However , I will consider your points and do more research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort method on the collections library allows you to pass a function to provide more ways of comparing the values on the list.
I would suggest adding this method on the foo class for example.

```
public static int compareFoo(Object a, Object b){
    if(!(a instanceof foo && b instanceof foo)){
        return Integer.compare(a.hashCode(), b.hashCode());
    }

    Foo firstArg = (Foo)a;
    Foo secondArg = (Foo)b;

    return firstArg.getStatus().compareTo(secondArg.getStatus());//implement a getter in the foo class.
}
```

Then the compare method is passed to the sort method in a lambda function.

```
 Collections.sort(ls,(a, b) ->  foo.compareFoo(a, b));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , I didn't know we can pass a function in on collections library.Thanks a lot

Comment: Class is spelled `Foo`, not `foo`, and method violates the contract of [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) for non-`Foo` objects: *The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`*.

Comment: The comparison for non-Foo objects is now based on hash code. I think is correct now. Is it fixed?